# Group total rows into a single row in dynamic pivot query

Tags: sql, pivot, dynamic-sql, sapb1

I have a working dynamic pivot query but am having a bit of trouble getting my Total row to display as a single row. Instead, it is giving me a Total row for each technician and a total row for my total column and invoiced amount column The invoiced column is also showing an incorrect total whereas the total column is correct.

Here is a sample of the result im currently getting. I've left off the Chargeable Utilzation as that is all correct by the looks of it.

| callID | StartDate | custMrName | Tech1 | Tech2 | Tech3 | Tech4 | Tech5 | Total | Invoiced | Chargeable Utilization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Total |  | 1.6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total | 2.2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total |  |  | 1.46 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total |  |  |  | 4.55 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total |  |  |  |  | 2.77 |  |  |  |
|  |  | Total |  |  |  |  |  | 12.58 | 28 |  |
| 123 | 1.12.23 | Cust1 | 0.65 |  | 0.34 |  |  | 0.99 | 1 |  |
| 234 | 1.12.23 | Cust2 |  | 1.10 |  |  |  | 1.10 | 2 |  |
| 456 | 1.12.23 | Cust3 |  |  | 1.12 |  |  | 1.12 | 2 |  |
| 567 | 1.12.23 | Cust4 | 0.67 |  |  |  |  | 0.67 | 1 |  |
| 678 | 1.12.23 | Cust5 |  | 0.50 |  |  | 1.64 | 2.14 | 2 |  |
| 789 | 1.12.23 | Cust6 |  |  |  | 4.55 |  | 4.55 | 5 |  |
| 890 | 1.12.23 | Cust7 | 0.88 |  |  |  | 1.13 | 2.01 | 2 |  |

And what Im trying to get is this.

| callID | StartDate | custMrName | Tech1 | Tech2 | Tech3 | Tech4 | Tech5 | Total | Invoiced | Chargeable Utilization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1.12.23 | Cust1 | 0.65 |  | 0.34 |  |  | 0.99 | 1 |  |
| 234 | 1.12.23 | Cust2 |  | 1.10 |  |  |  | 1.10 | 2 |  |
| 456 | 1.12.23 | Cust3 |  |  | 1.12 |  |  | 1.12 | 2 |  |
| 567 | 1.12.23 | Cust4 | 0.67 |  |  |  |  | 0.67 | 1 |  |
| 678 | 1.12.23 | Cust5 |  | 0.50 |  |  | 1.64 | 2.14 | 2 |  |
| 789 | 1.12.23 | Cust6 |  |  |  | 4.55 |  | 4.55 | 5 |  |
| 890 | 1.12.23 | Cust7 | 0.88 |  |  |  | 1.13 | 2.01 | 2 |  |
|  |  | Total | 2.2 | 1.6 | 1.46 | 4.55 | 2.77 | 12.58 | 15 |  |

Here is the code for the query, it is quite long so ive removed a couple sections related to calculating the technician times and invoiced amount.

```
DECLARE @FRDATE DATE = /* SELECT FROM OINV T0 WHERE T0.DocDate >= */  [%0];
DECLARE @TODATE DATE = /* SELECT FROM OINV T0 WHERE T0.DocDate <= */  [%1];
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)) [Technician]
                         FROM SCL6
                                  INNER JOIN OHEM ON SCL6.Technician = OHEM.empID
                                  INNER JOIN HEM6 ON HEM6.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
                                  INNER JOIN HTM1 ON HTM1.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
                         WHERE HEM6.roleID = -2 AND HTM1.teamID IN (1, 2) AND OHEM.Active = 'Y'
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                         , 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @techTime NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @techTime = ' /* section of code for calculating tech time';

DECLARE @invoiceQuantity NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @invoiceQuantity = ' /* section of code for calculating amount invoiced ';

SELECT @sql = '
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT T0.callID,
           T4.StartDate,
           T0.custMrName,
           CONCAT(OHEM.firstName, '' '', OHEM.lastName) AS Tech,
           ' + @techTime + ' AS Dur,
           B.Invoiced
    FROM OSCL T0
             INNER JOIN SCL6 T4 ON T0.callID = T4.SrcvCallID
             INNER JOIN OHEM ON T4.Technician = OHEM.empID
             INNER JOIN HEM6 ON HEM6.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
             INNER JOIN HTM1 ON HTM1.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
             ' + @invoiceQuantity + '
    WHERE T4.[Close] = ''Y'' AND
          T4.Technician <> 104 AND
          HEM6.roleID = -2 AND
          HTM1.teamID IN (1, 2) AND
          T0.customer <> ''C003435'' AND
          T4.StartDate BETWEEN @FRDATE AND @TODATE
    GROUP BY T0.callID, T4.StartDate, OHEM.firstName, OHEM.lastName, T4.Technician, T4.StartTime, T4.EndDate, T4.ChkInTime, T4.ChkOutTime, T4.EndTime, T4.ChkInDate, T4.ChkOutDate, B.Invoiced, T0.custMrName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T0.callID,
           T4.StartDate,
           T0.custMrName,
           ''Total'' AS ''Total'',
           ' + @techTime + ' AS Dur,
           B.Invoiced
    FROM OSCL T0
             INNER JOIN SCL6 T4 ON T0.callID = T4.SrcvCallID
             INNER JOIN OHEM ON T4.Technician = OHEM.empID
             INNER JOIN HEM6 ON HEM6.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
             INNER JOIN HTM1 ON HTM1.[empID] = OHEM.[empID]
             ' + @invoiceQuantity + '
          WHERE T4.[Close] = ''Y'' AND
          T4.Technician <> 104 AND
          HEM6.roleID = -2 AND
          HTM1.teamID IN (1, 2) AND
          T0.customer <> ''C003435'' AND
          T4.StartDate BETWEEN @FRDATE AND @TODATE
    GROUP BY T0.callID, T4.StartDate, T4.Technician, OHEM.firstName, OHEM.lastName, T4.StartTime, T4.EndDate, T4.ChkInTime, T4.ChkOutTime, T4.EndTime, T4.ChkInDate, T4.ChkOutDate, B.Invoiced, T0.custMrName
)

SELECT p.callID,
       p.StartDate,
       p.custMrName,
       ' + @columns + ',
       Total,
       Invoiced,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Invoiced, 0) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(CAST(ROUND(Invoiced / NULLIF(Total, 0) * 100,0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR) + ''%'' END AS [Chargeable Utilization]
FROM (
SELECT callID, StartDate, custMrName, Tech, Dur, Invoiced FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        NULL AS callID, 
        NULL AS StartDate, 
        ''Total'' AS custMrName, 
        Tech,
        SUM(Dur) AS Dur, 
        SUM(Invoiced) AS Invoiced 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Tech
) AS t
         PIVOT (SUM(Dur) FOR Tech IN (' + @columns + ',Total)) p
ORDER BY p.StartDate ASC';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@FRDATE DATE, @TODATE DATE', @FRDATE, @TODATE
```

Comment: The problem is that when you're pivoting the key is composed by callId, StartDate, custMrName and Invoiced whereas your purpose is to do an aggregation operation on Invoiced column.

Comment: Hi Gufus, thanks for the response. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this.

Comment: try to have a look at the result of "SELECT 
        NULL AS callID, 
        NULL AS StartDate, 
        ''Total'' AS custMrName, 
        Tech,
        SUM(Dur) AS Dur, 
        SUM(Invoiced) AS Invoiced 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Tech". I'm pretty sure that you will obtain many different rows with different Invoiced value. When you pivot Invoiced is not aggregated is considered a key field, that's why in the final result you have more than one total row.

Comment: I see what you mean Gufus, I removed the SUM(Invoiced) from the final select statement and made it NULL and the Total row showed up correctly. I'm not sure how to also pivot by the Invoiced field when PIVOT only allows one aggregate function. I looked into using UNPIVOT and CROSS APPLY but not sure how to translate that into this code.

Comment: the easiest thing maybe is a new CTE where you compute SUM(Invoiced) grouping by what you need. Another CTE will include the pivot. Then join these two CTE.

Comment: Hi Gufus, sorry to be a pain but can you show me what this looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I move here from the comments. Test something like this

```
with CTE as (...)

,CTE_a as (SELECT p.callID,
       p.StartDate,
       p.custMrName,
       ' + @columns + ',
       Total

FROM (
SELECT callID, StartDate, custMrName, Tech, Dur FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        NULL AS callID, 
        NULL AS StartDate, 
        ''Total'' AS custMrName, 
        Tech,
        SUM(Dur) AS Dur--, 
        --SUM(Invoiced) AS Invoiced 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Tech
) AS t
         PIVOT (SUM(Dur) FOR Tech IN (' + @columns + ',Total)) p
ORDER BY p.StartDate ASC)

,CTE_b as (SELECT callID, StartDate, custMrName, sum(Invoiced) as Invoiced FROM CTE group by callID, StartDate, custMrName
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        NULL AS callID, 
        NULL AS StartDate, 
        ''Total'' AS custMrName, 
        SUM(Invoiced) AS Invoiced 
    FROM CTE
    )

select a.*,b.invoiced
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.Invoiced, 0) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(CAST(ROUND(b.Invoiced / NULLIF(a.Total, 0) * 100,0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR) + ''%'' END AS [Chargeable Utilization]
    from CTE_a a
    inner join CTE_b b
    on isnull(a.callID,0)=isnull(b.callID,0)
    and isnull(a.StartDate,'99991231') =isnull(b.StartDate,'99991231')
    and a.custMrName=b.custMrName
```

in the final part pay attention when using CallID and StartDate in the join. In the "total" records you have some nulls to manage: if CallId is a positive integer I think that isnull(..,0) is a good solution; about StartDate I suggest '99991231', but the important thing is to choose a "fake" value, so outside of the actual range of values you can observe on StartDate. Otherwise I think that without these isnulls the join on total records is not going to work.

Comment: Hi Gufus, after a few minor adjustments this worked in giving me the aggregate for invoiced as well, however it looks like all the invoice values have been duplicated by the number of rows to give incorrect values.